# JHipster upgrade keep generating with previous Configuration

Tags: jhipster

A while back I generated a project with JHipster Registry, among other things (let's call it `conf1`). After a few months I realized I don't need it and changed everything I need to so my project would work properly (this one will be `conf2`) and it work as expected.

Now, every time I want to upgrade my project, JHipster generates everything based on `config1` instead of `config2`, which means my changes to get rid of anything I don't want, for instance JHipster Registry, get overridden by  the upgrade.

So my question is: what do I need to change so that every time I upgrade to a new JHipster version, I don't get it done based on `config1`?

Comment: Maybe you should change the options on your `jhipster_upgrade` branch in your git repo so that they are taken into account for next upgrade. See https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: Shouldn't the update delete the branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the `jhipster_upgrade` branch solved the issue.